# When to use は、に or no particle?

Tags: particles, particle-に, particle-は

I mostly understood the particles in Japanese, but there is still one thing I couldn't get over with. And that is the following problem:
I do not exactly know, when to use は、に or no particle. It's about the following three sentences:

- いつ勉強しますか
- 六時**に**起きます
- 今日**は**忙しいです

Why does the first sentence have no particle, the second one a に-particle and the last one a は-particle?
I can see a pattern in some way, but I can't figure out, why days use は, why times use に and why  does not use any particle

Comment: What is it about those three sentences that's troubling you? Some more detail would be helpful. Also, you say you "mostly understood the articles in Japanese" but Japanese does not have articles. I wonder if 'article' was an unfortunate choice of word or whether you have a fundamental misunderstanding about something.

Comment: @user3856370 Enrico Pucci wants to know how は and に are used with time expressions, which is a broad question, but I would like to provide an answer.

Comment: @Nameless Well, there's already a bunch of answers on that, though I dare say another one could be beneficial since they can be quite hard to search for. Have at it.

Comment: I'm still working on an answer, but perhaps reading this will help you: https://forum.duolingo.com/comment/32645170/I-am-busy-on-Saturday